# Likelihood of $f_\theta(x)=(1-\theta)\mathbf1_{[-1/2;0]}(x)+(1+\theta)\mathbf1_{]0;1/2]}(x)$

Tags: statistics, random-variables, estimation, maximum-likelihood, parameter-estimation

Let $(X_1,...,X_n)$ denote an i.i.d. random sample of size $n$ from the following distribution $f_\theta(x)$:

$$f_\theta(x)=(1-\theta)\mathbf1_{[-1/2;0]}(x)+(1+\theta)\mathbf1_{]0;1/2]}(x)$$

Let $x_i=(x_1,…,x_n)\in [-1/2;1/2]$, $u_n=\sum_{i=1}^n\mathbf1_{]-\infty;0]}(x_i)$ and $v_n=\sum_{i=1}^n\mathbf1_{]0;\infty[}(x_i)$

I don't understand why the likelihood is:

$$\mathcal{L}(x_1,...,x_n;\theta)=(1-\theta)^{u_n}(1+\theta)^{v_n}$$

And not:

$$\mathcal{L}(x_1,...,x_n;\theta)=(1-\theta)^{u_n}+(1+\theta)^{v_n}$$

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The joint density of an iid sample is the **product** of the individual marginal densities, not the sum.  So your likelihood cannot possibly be correct, since it is not formed by a product.

To understand what happened, we write things out step by step.  Instead of using indicator functions to specify the density, we will use piecewise notation:

$$f(x \mid \theta) = \begin{cases} 1-\theta, & -1/2 \le x \le 0 \\ 1+\theta, & 0 < x \le 1/2 \\ 0, & \text{otherwise}. \end{cases}$$

This way, we have made explicit the idea that for any given observation $x_i$ in the support $[-1/2,1/2]$, the value $f(x_i \mid \theta)$ is only ever $1-\theta$ or $1+\theta$.  It is never some combination of both.  Moreover, the only pertinent information about the $x_i$ is whether it is positive or non-positive in $[-1/2,1/2]$; we don't need to know the actual value, just whether it is positive, because once we know this, the value of $f$ is uniquely determined.

As such, it is natural to define auxiliary statistics that **count** the number of observations that are positive.  This is the purpose of introducing $u_n$ and $v_n$.  In particular, $v_n$ counts the number of positive observations, and $u_n$ counts the non-positive ones.  Of course, $u_n + v_n = n$ for all $n$, so we really only need to define one of these, say $v_n$.

Then our joint likelihood for the iid sample $(x_1, \ldots, x_n)$ can be written as

$$\mathcal L(\theta \mid x_1, \ldots, x_n) = \prod_{i=1}^n f(x_i \mid \theta) = (1 - \theta)^{u_n} (1 + \theta)^{v_n} = (1-\theta)^{n - v_n} (1+\theta)^{v_n},$$ because if $u_n$ represents the number of non-positive observations, each one of these contributes a multiplicative factor of $1-\theta$ to the likelihood; similarly, there are $v_n$ positive observations, each of which contributes $1+\theta$.

If this is still confusing, it is helpful to consider an example with a specified sample size.  Say $n = 7$, and the sample is
$$(x_1, \ldots, x_7) = (0.2, 0.1, -0.3, -0.4, 0.3, 0.4, 0.1).$$  Then for $i \in \{1, 2, 5, 6, 7\}$, the $x_i$ are positive, and for $i \in \{3, 4\}$, the $x_i$ are negative.  The positive ones each satisfy $f(x_i \mid \theta) = 1+\theta$.  The negative ones each satisfy $f(x_i \mid \theta) = 1-\theta$.  So for example, $f(0.2 \mid \theta) = 1+\theta$.  This is just using the definition we are given.

Now, how many of the observations are positive?  $v_7 = 5$.  And $u_7 = 2$.  So the total likelihood is just $(1-\theta)^2 (1+\theta)^5$.  As we can see, it doesn't matter which of the $x_i$ are positive, nor does it matter what their values are, only their sign.

Comment: Thank you very much!